# How to move repeated files from folder to another in php?

Tags: php, file-rename, scandir

I want to scan my whatsapp images folder and move all the repeated images to folder named `recycle bin` to delete them later, here is my code:

```
<?php

$dir    = 'C:\wamp\www\whatsapp';
$files = scandir($dir);

$x = 0;

foreach($files as $f1)
{

    $crc1 = strtoupper(dechex(crc32(file_get_contents("whatsapp/".$f1))));

    unset($files[$x]);

    $j = 0;

    foreach($files as $f2)
    {

        $crc2 = strtoupper(dechex(crc32(file_get_contents("whatsapp/".$f2))));

        if($crc1 == $crc2){

            rename("whatsapp/".$f2, "recycle bin/".$f2);

            unset($files[$j]);
        }

        $j++;
    }

    $x++;
}

exit('Done');
```

does this code seems to be trusted to move only the repeated images without any mistakes?

Comment: It's very inefficient. Just hash each file once, put the hash in an array, and if the next file has a hash that's already in the array, you know you can move it... instead of hashing every single file all over again to see if there's a dupe.

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ not on SO.

Comment: @rjdown could you write an example?

Answer (score 1):

I've write a small script for your case (but i have not tested its):

```
<?php

$fileHashes = [];

foreach(scandir('C:\wamp\www\whatsapp') as $file){
    $fileHashes["whatsapp/".$file] = sha1(file_get_contents("whatsapp/".$file));
}

$doubles = array_diff_key($fileHashes, array_unique($fileHashes))
foreach($doubles as $file=>$hash){
    unlink($file);
}

exit('Done');
```